# Generate bitmap from GestureOverlayView

Tags: java, android

I have an app that needs to capture a customer's signature and then present it in an ImageView. For proof-of-concept, I've written a small app that has a layout with a GestureOverlayView at the top, then a "Save Signature" button, then an ImageView below. When I press the Save Signature button, it should create an image from the GestureOverlayView and display it in the ImageView. Below is the code/layout and then a list of issues:

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView android:id="@+id/GestureView" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" 
        android:fadeEnabled="false"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
        android:gestureStrokeWidth="1.5"
        android:gestureColor="#000000"
        android:fadeOffset="600000"
        android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="false"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true">
    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
    <Button android:id="@+id/SubmitButton"  
        android:text="Save Signature" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView iv;
    GestureOverlayView gv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        gv = (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.GestureView);

        Button submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(gv.getDrawingCache());
                iv.setImageBitmap(b);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I get a Null Pointer exception every time on the createBitmap() method. I believe it is because gv.getDrawingCaches() is returning null. As you can see, drawing cache IS enabled so it should return SOMETHING!

Here's the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:358)
    at com.pgov.barcode.TestActivity$2.onClick(TestActivity.java:42)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You get a null pointer exception where? Please post your stack trace, and indicate the line that throws the exception.

Comment: Updated main post, sorry I was on my way out to lunch and posted quickly ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I answered my own question. Even though I used:

```
android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
```

I changed the code to:

```
gv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(gv.getDrawingCache());
iv.setImageBitmap(b);
gv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

And it works! Not sure why the XML flag doesn't affect it though...